# Xamarin turn-by-turn navigation with routing and HERE

Tags: here-api

I am using Xamarin iOS and Android for turn-by-turn navigation routing. Can this be done with HERE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend using android studio. For Xamarin, bindings need to be created in SDK, which are not available in our existing roadmap. Hence you can either create the bindings yourself or using our professional services as SDK libraries need modification in this case. Yes it is available. It can be done.

Please refer the individual documentation for Android and Ios for more details :

Android : https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html

IOS : https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-guidance.html